# Is syntactic understanding of a text actually the most elementary form of semantical understanding of the text?

Tags: syntax, semantics, morphosyntax

I am not a Linguist, but I am curious about the question below:

Is there a linguistic theory that points out that syntactic understanding of a text constitutes the lowest level of semantical understanding of the text?

I think it is true that the syntactic understanding of a text can be said as the most elementary form of semantical knowledge of the text, since if we do not understand the syntax of a language, we can't really understand any semantics (since a lack of syntactic understanding implies the lack of familiarity with the language).

In other words, can syntactic understanding of a text be classified as the most basic form of semantic understanding of the text (i.e. that is, syntactic knowledge is essentially a particular type (the most basic type) of a semantic knowledge)? If yes, is there any academic paper that talks addresses this topic?

I hope I made my question clear.

Thank you,

Comment: Most basic compared to what?

Comment: What is "syntactic understanding", and how is it different from "semantic(al) understanding"?

Comment: It’s not as you say but look at lexical semantics, which combines with syntax to provide a basis for formal semantics — in this sense syntax is the basis for meaning but the pieces of meaning (the “building blocks”) come from the lexicon.